# Meteor helper doesn't refresh on Reactive var .set()

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper, meteor-react

I update reactive var on `autorun`. The same reactive var is used in `helper`. But `helper` values doesn't refresh by `autorun` function. My below code will explain you clearly.

```
Template.home.onCreated(function () {
  var self = this;
  self.ITEMS_INCREMENT = 2;

  self.itemsLimit = new ReactiveVar(2);


});

Template.home.onRendered(function () {
  var self = this;
  this.autorun(function(){
    if( true ){
      self.itemsLimit.set(self.itemsLimit.get()+self.ITEMS_INCREMENT);
      console.log(self.itemsLimit.get()); // set values are fine
    }
  });

});

Template.home.helpers({
testHelper: function(){
  console.log(Template.instance().itemsLimit.get()); // console returns 2 and 4 only. no more update :(
  return true;
}
});
```

Anything wrong in handling of data or usage? How to make helpers are workable?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish and what did you expect to happen? What does your template markup look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well well well, I don't see where are you going to change the value of reactive variable. It gets changed only ones, when first computation runs in your tracker. So only ones you see the update. The idea of using `ReactiveVar` is that when you change it, it gets changed inside helper or inside autorun.

Briefly, what you can do to test it is:

```
Template.home.onRendered(function () {
  var self = this;
  Meteor.setInterval(function(){
      self.itemsLimit.set(self.itemsLimit.get()+self.ITEMS_INCREMENT);
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @ZuzEL. But I have a doubt, does `setInterval` approach is good??

Comment: No, it's not in any sense good. It's just to test how `ReactiveVar` works. You should change reactive var depending on goal that you need to achieve. For example when clicking button.